# Backing up files from specific folders in rsync

Tags: backup, rsync

How can I specify specific files to include/exclude in grsync/rsync?

Currently, I use different operations to backup files from only specified folders. I want to do it now in 1 pass. I think I should be looking at the include/exclude options?

Suppose I have a folder structure like

```
/
  /inc1
    /inc1.1
    /...
  /inc2
    /...
  /exc1
  files in root here ...
```

I want to only backup files/folders from inc1 & inc2 how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use --include and --exclude options or for a backup process you may want to use --include-from so you can list the folders you want to back up in a file.

For example your file may be called includes.txt and save in your home directory.
It would contain

```
  inc1/
  inc2/
```

And the rsync command to back up folders inc1 and inc2 in your home directory would be

```
rsync $HOME --include-from=~/includes.txt /home/backup/
```

rsync is very flexible, you are best off consulting the man page first and if you get stuck asking a more specific question.

Comment: When testing rsync use options -nv which will show you what it will do without actually doing it.

Answer (score 4):

To include only specific directories, include them and their contents, then exclude `*`. If the directories aren't at the root, you need to include every directory leading to them. For example, to include only `/source/inc1`, `/source/inc2` and `/source/also/included`:

```
rsync -a --include='/inc1/***' --include='/inc2/***' \
         --include='/also' --include='/also/included/***' \
         --exclude='*' /source /target
```

See also [a quick guide to common rsync filters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503).

Comment: The answer is perfect, though one need to reed carefully. To backup `--include='/also/included/***'` one does first need to include the parent folder `--include='/also'`. Forgetting to do so skips `'/also/included/***'` completely.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you can just specify those folders to rsync:

```
rsync -Pav /inc1 /inc2 /path/to/backup/folder/
```

This will create:

```
/path/to/backup/folder/inc1/
/path/to/backup/folder/inc1/inc1.1/
/path/to/backup/folder/inc1/...
/path/to/backup/folder/inc2/
/path/to/backup/folder/inc2/...
```

Comment: When you want to use a remote server as the source, I'm guessing you'd have to add user@server: before every folder. I just tried `rsync -nav root@server:/etc/psa root@server:/usr/local/psa /localdir/` and it didn't work. So I think this technique only works with local sources.

Comment: @ChadvonNau: rsync will work with at most one remote (ie, either a remote source or a remote destination). In your example, you're using both a remote source and a remote destination.

Comment: I was attempting to do two remote source folders and a local destination. Trying to apply your two source technique to a remote host situation.

Comment: @ChadvonNau: Ah, I didn't interpret the newline as a space there! In that case, try `rsync -nav 'root@server:{/etc,/usr/local}/psa' /localdir/`

Comment: That's awesome. It doesn't maintain the directory structure the way doing it with an includes file would, but it's way easier to setup.